# MongoDB: aggregation group by a field in large collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a large (millions) collection of files where tags is an array field like this.

```
{
    "volume" : "abc", 
    "name" : "file1.txt", 
    "type" : "txt", 
    "tags" : [ "Interesting", "Weird" ], ...many other fields
}
```

Now I want to return count of unique tags for the entire collection. I am using `aggregate` for that. Here's my query.

```
db.files.aggregate(
    { "$match" : {"volume":"abc"}},
    { "$project" : { "tags" : 1}},
    { "$unwind" : "$tags"},
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$tags" , "count" : { "$sum" : 1}}},
    { "$sort" : { "count" : 1}}
)
```

I am seeing that it takes around 3 seconds for this to return for a collection of 1.2M files. I do have index on `tags` and `volume` fields.

I am using MongoDB 2.4. Since 2.6 is not out, I cannot use the `.explain()` here.

Any ideas how I can improve this performance? I do need to have a summary count. Also, I cannot pre-compute these counts as my `$match` will be variable based on volume, type, a particular tag, some date time of file etc.

Comment: You are worried about performance because you need this report regularly? As far as I know unwind is a performance killer

Comment: Yes, this query is run in UI real-time by via a user action.

Comment: I have a suggestion in that case. Create a additional collection to hold the tags. Whenever the user adds a tag, update tag collection along with the original collection. You would be having tags in two places, in the main doc as well as in the new collection. This will give you good performance.

Comment: Actually, though not documented if you have 2.4.9 then you can use explain. The output in either case doesn't show much more than an index used and of course the content of the pipeline.

Comment: As to your actual question(s), some information is missing. For the given query exactly how many documents are matching the initial `$match` statement (which will use an index)? Also what is the largest size of the `tags` array for a document in that match? And you could consider what is the average size as well. If either of those array numbers are over 500 then you could well have problems.

Comment: @NeilLunn after the `$match` I have about 1.2M documents. The largest size of tags is not specified currently but on average I have about 1-2 tags.